Does connecting the ground of a power source to the neutral of the lamp cause a short circuit?
Does connecting the ground of a power source to the neutral of the lamp cause a short circuit?
In other words, would either of the connections below cause a short circuit?


They wouldn't be legal in most countries.

the two circuits are identical, because the lamp has no knowledge of which terminal should be hot

Neither of your circuits provide a direct path between Line and Neutral or Line and Ground (which may be connected to Neutral at the local transformer or utility supply point).
Since there is no direct path there is no short-circuit.
Neither circuit is wired properly and both may present an electrocution hazard to the user.

Additionally, those circuits would trip gfci breakers if present.
